# Testing backend timeout with Restassured

Tags: rest-assured

I'm using RestAssured 2.4.1 to test a service stack whose first service is exposed via REST.

Now, I want to test the behaviour when the backend is not responding, a situation that the REST service is supposed to detect and handle. Unfortunately, RestAssured terminates the POST request before the REST service detects the backend timeout.

How can I increase the corresponding timeout of RestAssured? I'm trying the following without success

```
RestAssuredConfig config = RestAssured.config();
config.getHttpClientConfig()
            .setParam(ClientPNames.CONN_MANAGER_TIMEOUT, 0)  // HttpConnectionManager connection return time
            .setParam(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 0) // Remote host connection time
            .setParam(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT,  0) ; // Remote host response time

given()
    .config(config)
    . ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using RestAssured 3.0.1, but this is how I fixed this - yet globally (I actually wanted to lower the default timeout). I also use the SystemDefaultHttpClient, as I want to reuse connections (HTTP keepalive). Thus it does not fit 100%, but might give pointers.

```
HttpClientConfig clientConfig = RestAssured.config().getHttpClientConfig();
clientConfig = clientConfig.httpClientFactory(new HttpClientConfig.HttpClientFactory() {
    @Override
    public HttpClient createHttpClient() {
        HttpClient rv =  new SystemDefaultHttpClient();
        HttpParams httpParams = rv.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5 * 1000); //Wait 5s for a connection
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 60 * 1000); // Default session is 60s
        return rv;
    }
});

//This is necessary to ensure, that the client is reused.
clientConfig = clientConfig.reuseHttpClientInstance();

RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().httpClient(clientConfig);
```

Answer (score -1):

What exactly is timing out?

If your test is using [org.junit.Test](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) then you can set the timeout explicitly. The following sets the timeout to 60 seconds (60000 milliseconds):

```
@Test(timeout = 60000)
public void canCallFullyQualifiedUrlsWithoutPortDefined() throws Exception {
    // This test hangs forever unless it works
    get("http://filehost-semc-rss-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/testfile1.txt");
}
```

You can get the actual response time from rest-assured:

```
@Test public void
response_time_can_be_extracted() {
    long time =
    given().
            param("firstName", "John").
            param("lastName", "Doe").
    when().
            get("/greet").
    then().
            extract().response().time();

    assertThat(time, greaterThan(0L));
}
```

Comment: This does not help at all. This question is about increasing the timeout, not terminating it even earlier.

Comment: @morty Did it cross your mind that in that case you should set the timeout higher than 60000? Amusing.

Comment: The question clearly states that RestAssured times out. Setting or increasing the time before Junit terminates the test does not solve the problem as it has absolutely no effect on RestAssured. Your answer would be correct if Junit had a default timeout that was lower than RestAssured's timeout and increasing that would solve the problem.